# Compare max of lower nodes with upper nodes

Tags: r, statistics

I have a rather complex problem. I have different Companies and also different buyers. Furthermore I have also different Products, which can go up to 15 Products. 
All Products have a `Price`. This `Price` goes for different Product Sets, which have the Name, `Product - Set 1` to `Product - Set 6`, in my example.

Now I want to loop through all `Companies` and check their `Buyers` and test if the price of all `Product Sets 1 to 6(in my example)` is the maximum on the `Product - ALL` node,for the same selection of `Company` and `Buyer`.

I tried this with one example:

```
> dput(sys)
structure(list(Company = c("Company 1", "Company 2", "Company 3", 
"Company 2", "Company 2", "Company 2", "Company 3", "Company 3", 
"Company 5", "Company 5", "Company 5", "Company 2", "Company 2", 
"Company 2", "Company 2", "Company 2"), Buyer = c("Buyer 1", 
"Buyer 2", "Buyer 1", "Buyer 1", "Buyer 1", "Buyer 2", "Buyer 2", 
"Buyer 1", "Buyer 3", "Buyer 1", "Buyer 3", "Buyer 2", "Buyer 2", 
"Buyer 2", "Buyer 2", "Buyer 2"), Products = c("Product - ALL", 
"Product - Set 1", "Product - Set 2", "Product - Set 1", "Product - ALL", 
"Product - ALL", "Product - ALL", "Product - Set 1", "Product - ALL", 
"Product - Set 1", "Product - Set 2", "Product - Set 2", "Product - Set 3", 
"Product - Set 4", "Product - Set 5", "Product - Set 6"), Price = c(NA, 
10L, 99L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 12L, NA, 
11L, 0L, 12L)), .Names = c("Company", "Buyer", "Products", "Price"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000100788>)
> 
> df <- sys[ (sys$Company =="Company 2" & sys$Buyer == "Buyer 2"), ]
> 
> #replace all NAs with 0
> df[is.na(df)] <- 0
> 
> #Fill control column with null
> df$ControlColumn <- "null"
> 
> if(grep("Product - ALL", df)) {
+  i <- grep("Product - ALL", df)
+  prodSet1 <- grep("Product - Set 1", df$Products)
+  prodSet2 <- grep("Product - Set 2", df$Products)
+  prodSet3 <- grep("Product - Set 3", df$Products)
+  prodSet4 <- grep("Product - Set 4", df$Products)
+  prodSet5 <- grep("Product - Set 5", df$Products)
+  prodSet6 <- grep("Product - Set 6", df$Products)
+  val <- max(df[prodSet1]$Price, df[prodSet2]$Price,df[prodSet3]$Price,df[prodSet4]$Price,df[prodSet5]$Price,df[prodSet6]$Price)
+  df[i]$Price == val
+  df[i]$ControlColumn <- (df[i]$Price == val)
+ }
```

However, I am struggeling to automate this task for the input data. Any recommendation how to automate this process for this complex problem?

I appreciate your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make much better use of the fact that your `sys` data set is a `data.table`.

First, you can find `Products` with highest price for a given `Company` and `Buyer` (and we don't want those products to be `Products - All`):

```
max.prices <- sys[Products!='Product - ALL',.SD[which.max(Price)],by=.(Company,Buyer)]
#      Company   Buyer        Products Price
# 1: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 2    12
# 2: Company 3 Buyer 1 Product - Set 2    99
# 3: Company 2 Buyer 1 Product - Set 1    13
# 4: Company 5 Buyer 1 Product - Set 1   100
# 5: Company 5 Buyer 3 Product - Set 2   100
```

`max.prices` might be useful for other purposes in further analysis, so you might want to create another data set rather than modifying `max.prices`:

```
all.prods <- max.prices
all.prods[,Products:='Product - ALL']
#      Company   Buyer      Products Price
# 1: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - ALL    12
# 2: Company 3 Buyer 1 Product - ALL    99
# 3: Company 2 Buyer 1 Product - ALL    13
# 4: Company 5 Buyer 1 Product - ALL   100
# 5: Company 5 Buyer 3 Product - ALL   100
```

Now, all 'Product - All' entries can be replaced by the updated ones:

```
result <- rbind(all.prods,sys[Products!='Product - ALL'])
```

The code below sorts the result and prints it out:

```
setkey(result,Company,Buyer)    
result
#      Company   Buyer        Products Price
#  1: Company 2 Buyer 1   Product - ALL    13
#  2: Company 2 Buyer 1 Product - Set 1    13
#  3: Company 2 Buyer 2   Product - ALL    12
#  4: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 1    10
#  5: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 2    12
#  6: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 3    NA
#  7: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 4    11
#  8: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 5     0
#  9: Company 2 Buyer 2 Product - Set 6    12
# 10: Company 3 Buyer 1   Product - ALL    99
# 11: Company 3 Buyer 1 Product - Set 2    99
# 12: Company 3 Buyer 1 Product - Set 1    99
# 13: Company 5 Buyer 1   Product - ALL   100
# 14: Company 5 Buyer 1 Product - Set 1   100
# 15: Company 5 Buyer 3   Product - ALL   100
# 16: Company 5 Buyer 3 Product - Set 2   100
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! After sorting it, how can I show if the Produc - All price is correctly the aggregated values from the lower nodes? Because my goal is to check rather than to replace?

Comment: I basically want a colume that marks the `Product - ALL` node with `TRUE`, if it is calculated properly.

Comment: Could you try  `sys[,ControlColumn:=(Products=='Product - ALL' & Price==max(Price,na.rm=T)),by=.(Company,Buyer)]` and see if it produces the result you expect?